# Get the current index position in a list when creating a new object in a linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, mapper

I'm having problems accessing the current position from a LINQ list when creating a new object

I have tried to declare a variable and increment it inside the new object for no result. I have no other ideas. Search for some time in linq expressions but can't find an answer

```
var mapper = Singleton.CreateMapper<DocOutput, List<Document>>();
mapper.AddMapping(r => r.Docs, i => i, (x) => new Document() 
{
    Id = x.ElementAt( Index Position ).Extrato1.Split('.')[0],
}
```

In the Index Position i would need the current object position.

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what mapping library are you using?

Comment: Hi, it's a inhouse mapper solution based on tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I understand your problem correctly**, you have `List<Document>` object and you need to walk this list through having an index of each step for creating some other object.
You return value is a mapping (I'd use dictionary here) - *IEnumerable* of `Tuple<int, object>`

Why don't you simply use `select` for creating your tuples like this:

```
var mapper = new List<Document>();

var mapping = mapper.
                  Select((doc, n) => new System.Tuple<int, Document>(n, doc));
```

Of course `select` can return your own type already, I assume `AddMapping` is your own extension method, nevertheless to get a list of tuples of *your index* and *Document* you'd most likely have to run the following:

```
var mapper = new List<Document>();

var mapping = mapper.
                  Select((doc, n) => 
                         new System.Tuple<int, Document>(doc.ElementAt(n).Extrato1.Split('.')[0], doc));
```

Let me know it this is what you need.